# Cannot update packages although update exists

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, updates

I am trying to update some packages in ubutnu 20.04 in order to update to 22.04.1. Upgrade is failing because it's asking me to update my packages. Running
`sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt list --upgradeable -a` I get the following packages

```shell
steam-installer/bionic,bionic 1:1.0.0.59-4pop2~18.04 all [upgradeable from: 1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3]
steam-installer/focal,focal,now 1.0.0.61-2ubuntu3 all [installed,upgradeable to: 1:1.0.0.59-4pop2~18.04]
```

Running `sudo apt full-upgrade` I get the following

```shell
sudo apt full-upgrade        
Reading packages list... Done
Creating dependency tree                 
Reading current state... Done
Calculating update... Done
0 updated, 0 installded, 0 removed and 0 not upgraded.
```

(Actual text was in a different language and translated on the fly). Why doesn't it update my packages ?

Comment: What OS are you actually using? as one of the two packages is intended for Pop OS & not Ubuntu; your sources don't appear to be all Ubuntu if you're using Ubuntu, or are you using Pop OS?

Comment: I think `steam-installer/bionic,bionic 1:1.0.0.59-4pop2~18.04` should have been removed a long time ago. It is not for 20.04 and not from the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1):

The was an issue with the steam package as a dependency for `steam-installer`. I don't know how the "pop" dependency slipped there. The solution was to uninstall them both to proceed with the upgrade to ubuntu 22.04.1. The whole process was the following.

1. Ran `apt update && apt full-upgrade && apt autoremove` to update packages
2. ran `update-manager -c -d` and started upgrade to 22.04
3. update failed due to insufficient space in /boot
4. Uninstalled older kernel
5. updated grub
6. Ran `update-manager -c -d` Updated pakcages removed old kernel remains
7. Upgrade failed due to pakcages need upagrade

Maybe somewhere between 2nd and third bullet this update slipped there, I don't know, but I don't remember installing it.

Comment: Use of the `-d` flag is unwise. 22.04 is not the development release of Ubuntu anymore.